# PHPExcel_Reader_Exception recognised as an OLE file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, phpexcel

Please help me reading an excel file upload attached. When I attach an XLS format, my PHPExcel reader is not working. Do you think where am I missing?

HTML

```
<form role="form" id="myForm" class="add_customer_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="fileUpload">Upload File *</label>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="file[]" class="form-control"
      accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel"
    multiple required>
</form>
```

AJAX

//USAGE: $("#form").serializefiles();

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.serializefiles = function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        /* ADD FILE TO PARAM AJAX */
        var formData = new FormData();
        $.each($(obj).find("input[type='file']"), function(i, tag) {
            $.each($(tag)[0].files, function(i, file) {
                formData.append(tag.name, file);
            });
        });
        var params = $(obj).serializeArray();
        $.each(params, function (i, val) {
            formData.append(val.name, val.value);
        });
        return formData;
    };
})(jQuery);

$.ajax({
    url: base_url+'customer/customer_add',
    type: 'POST',
    data: values,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){ 
            console.log(data);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
foreach($_FILES["file"]['name'] as $file => $fname) {
    $file_path  = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$file];
    $extension = pathinfo($fname);

    if($extension['extension'] == 'xls') {
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');    
    }
    else {
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    }
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($file_path);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file_path);

    $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();
    print_r($cell_collection); die();
}
```

DISPLAY ERROR

[image: displayerror]

Answer (score 1):

Don't trust the file extension.... that `xls` file is not a native Excel BIFF-format file, no matter what extension it might claim. It's quite common to find `.xls` used as an extension for csv files, or files containing html markup.

Use the IO Factory's `identify()` method to tell you what reader to use; or just simply use the IO Factory `load()` method to select the correct reader and load the file for you.

Comment: I found an error in File. How can i fix the file before upload to codeigniter php? It says, The file format and extension dont match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its sournce etc..

Comment: If you get that "error", then it's telling you that the file with a `.xls` extension isn't really a genuine xls file...... let the identify() method work out what it really is as I've told you in my answer